# JsPDF add box-shadow

Tags: javascript, css, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>JS PDF Demo</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.25/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js" integrity="sha512-SgWewGM3r8xXm8LNXt4ZHqKVKu/7eKrJ1aBCbMaX44xXXaCcIvCAvD2kj9qnC1lhyjAu04mcPiTzcc/CaACnUQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js" integrity="sha512-BNaRQnYJYiPSqHHDb58B0yaPfCu+Wgds8Gp/gU33kqBtgNS4tSPHuGibyoeqMV/TJlSKda6FXzoEyYGjTe+vXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
                box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
            }
    
            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }
    
            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
            
        </style>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
              <td>Maria Anders</td>
              <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
              <td>Francisco Chang</td>
              <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ernst Handel</td>
              <td>Roland Mendel</td>
              <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Island Trading</td>
              <td>Helen Bennett</td>
              <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
              <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
              <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
              <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
              <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    
    <script>
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    
    
        doc.html(document.body, {
        callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save();
        }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`

I want to add box-shadow to my PDF output. Currently, I'm using the jsPDF library to generate PDF files.

Contents are printing fine.

Only the challenge I'm facing is, that I'm not able to add box-shadow.

I run through the core library and that doesn't have any API methods with box-shadow.

I tried to write my own API method's also, but couldn't make it.

Any help would be appreciated.

If want to add API, please guide me on that also, I will also contribute to the community. So, it will be helpful for all like us in the future.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks buddy. But the example you posted not looks like box shadow. Let's see if anyone can help out. If someone suggest how to write API, I'll happy to write, even it'll be useful for larger community.

Comment: In your example, you're trying to shadow (drop shadow) the entire document. But my requirement is, to do different shadows for each container in a single pdf file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to add box-shadow to the given table. In output I'm able to see the box shadow, but when downloaded as a PDF it's omitting the box-shadow.

I suppose to get the box-shadow in pdf also.

created a fiddle also

https://jsfiddle.net/9pqom48x/